# AdMob on iOS using Robopods and LibGDX

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, admob

I have already implemented AdMob using interfaces for android and I have now added the code of dependencies for using AdMob with Robopods for iOS. However, I am unsure. Do I need to add any code specifically for the iOS part of the project or should my ads work on iOS alredy. (p.s. I am coding using a windows PC hence why I cannot test on iOS)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to implement bindings for Android and iOS separately by initializing AdMob and setting ad views (assuming you have working  AdMob integration in Android) just like you did in AndroidLauncher class. You also need to initialize AdMob iOS SDK and define some ad views in iOSLauncher class or some other iOS specific class.

Comment: @Burak Thank you for the reply, where can I find the code to use after I have added the bindings. The iOS system is a different language but LibGDX writes in Java, where can I find the java code for adding ads on iOS

Comment: As it's a binding, all classes and methods are the same with iOS SDK of AdMob. Check the "Get Started" guide to AdMob iOS and you will be able to use same classes and methods just written with Java. You can google for tutorials but most of them seems outdated. Give a shot with: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx#ios-setup-robovm

Comment: Hi @BurakKurkcu, I have changed to using chartboost. Okay so what I have done now is set-up chartboost on android and added the robopods bindings in my dependencies. I have created interfaces but now I do not know what to do. You say to use the normal code but this is Java and I do not know how to translate the chartboost code to java. PLEASE help, I am stuck and I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Chartboost SDK is the most easy SDK that I've used on libGDX. First of all enable test mode from the chartboost dashboard not to waste impressions. Then check https://gist.github.com/burakkurkcu/6f2b5a54e2df9d90fffa for both iOS and Android implementations.

Comment: thank you for that, but how would you show the ad on your app, you have no ShowInterstital method? and wouldn't the name of the method be from the same interface as you are calling the showinterstitial method from the core project, which is for both android and iOS?

Comment: check inline comments in both files under chartboost initialization you will see that I described how to use also.

Comment: Yes, sorry I just saw it. Thank you, I will try to use it when I can but I do not have a mac to test it out on yet.

Have you created a fully functional android and iOS app using LibGDX and tested on both platforms?

Comment: Also, should I implement the interface I am using to showInterstital ads on my iOS launcher as I cannot call showinterstitial directly from the core project, I have to call it from iOSLauncher but this has no method to call it from.?

Comment: You need to create an interface to define actions like showIntersititial on core module's source and implement it in IOSLauncher and AndroidLauncher to write platform specific codes under methods. Then you can pass the classes that implements your ads interface as a parameter to main class. So you can call showInterstitial from core and treat it as you need in each platform.

Comment: Okay! thank you so much, I have done that and I will test it when I can!

Comment: Hi, I have tested it. Chart boost works for android but not for iOS. I am calling it by calling the interface which is implanted in iOSLauncher as:

public void showChartBoostInterstitial() {
        Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.Default);

    }

Other than that I have simply copied your code but it does not work. Please help